# python global variables as arguments

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I have a global variable in one function that is used as an argument for another. How can I use it as an argument without the second function changing it?

Example:

```
variable = []

def bar(x):
    x[2] = 4
    print x

def foo():
    global variable 
    variable = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    bar(variable)
    print variable
```

Running `foo()` like this would output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 4]
```

When I want it to print:

```
[1, 2, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So is there a way to keep the original global variable for future use while still using it in the other function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the contents of the list to be passed to `bar`, but you don't want the alterations to affect the original list, then copy the list as you pass it in. You can do that just by changing:

```
bar(variable)
```

to:

```
bar(variable[:])
```

The `[]` notation can be used to create slices of lists, which are copies of particular ranges of indexes.
`[:]` specifically gives you a copy of the whole list.

Comment: Idk why this was downvoted, but this is the correct answer, perhaps you should mention that variable[:] slices the list to make a copy of the full list.

Comment: @user3467349 I don't know either. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a copy of the list, just use `bar(variable[:])`.
Like this:

```
variable = []

def bar(x):
    x[2] = 4
    print x

def foo():
    global variable 
    variable = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    bar(variable[:])
    print variable
```

This will output:

```
>>> foo()
[1, 2, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```